# How to learn guild's id at add reaction (messageReactionAdd event)

Tags: discord.js

I want to create a command as Zira Bot. If you don't know Zira, the command is reaction role. So, at reaction add, if reaction emoji is 'bla bla', add role 'bla bla'. But I need to learn the guild's id.

I have tried `reaction.guild.id` and `user.guild.id`, but it hasn't worked.

My code is:

```
Bot.on ('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    const fs = require ('fs')
    const reactionRole = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./Util/Reaction Role.json'))
    const reactionRoleEmoji = reactionRole[reaction.guild.id].reaction
    const reactionRoleRole = reactionRole[reaction.guild.id].role
    if (reaction.emoji.id === reactionRoleEmoji) user.addRole(reactionRoleRole)
})
```

It errors "the property "id" of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reaction` has a message property, and message has `guild`.

```
reaction.message.guild.id
```